# How to replace a rectangular region of Mat image

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing

I am working with opencv image processing library. I just want to replace rectangular region(smaller than the original image) of my original Mat image with another small image. I couldn't find a direction to do this

Can anybody help me please. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7):

Here's a way, not claiming its the best way.

```
Mat m = ... // your smaller mat
Mat submat= matOrig.submat(new Rect(x,y, m.cols(), m.rows()) );
m.copyTo(submat);
```

That should work assuming m doesn't go out of bounds inside matOrig.  When you get a submat, it is still linked to its source Mat.

Comment: Does this automatically update the original image :( I tried this but nothing will change in original image it will only update the submat that we extract from the original ..
Any way thank you for the help

Comment: It should update the original.  Are you sure you aren't first making a copy of the submat and then copying to the copy?

Comment: I just wrote a small method using Java to update a part of an image. Is it because of Java?  
Here is my method  
  `public void ChangeImage(Mat src, Mat small, Rect roi){
  
        Mat subView =src.submat(roi);    
       small.copyTo(subView);  
       Highgui.imwrite("combined-image.png", src);  
 } `

Comment: Your code works for me on OpenCV 2.4.9.  Are you sure you're setting the right values for Rect roi?  Here's how I created roi in my test:       Rect rect = new Rect(20, 20, small.cols(), small.rows());  Not sure how much Java you've done, but I'd also suggest using Java conventions and naming your methods in lowercase:  changeImage(...)

Comment: Sorry, I did some wrong editing and rolled it back, I had missed this was Java, that has no operator overloading :)

Comment: I had a huge troubles with small.copyTo(large, mask); I think there is  some bug in openCV 2.4.12. However small.copy(mask); works like charm!!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my kotlin code for this:

```
    val shifted = Mat.zeros(image.size(), image.type())
    val copiedSize = Size(image.width() - abs(pixelOffset.x), image.height() - abs(pixelOffset.y))

    val fromStartPoint = Point()
    val toStartPoint = pixelOffset.clone()

    val fromRect = Rect(fromStartPoint, copiedSize)
    val toRect = Rect(toStartPoint, copiedSize)
    image.submat(fromRect).copyTo(shifted.submat(toRect))
    return shifted
```

Answer (score -1):

This is my code:

```
Mat m = new Mat(originalImg,new Rect(x,y,w, h));
double[] size = {w, h};
Imgproc.resize(logo,logo,new Size(size));// make sure your logo is the same size with your roi
Imgproc.cvtColor(logo, logo, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2RGB);//make sure your logo has the same channel with your dst img
congrats.copyTo(m);
```