# How could I write a roi of a cvMat in openCV using java?

Tags: java, opencv, mat

I am using java with openCV and I need to write a region of interest into a bigger matrix. Is there a way different to a for-loop ?

i.e, write a cvMat 50x40 into a cvMat 200x200

I know it's possible to extract a roi of a cvMat but I've not found a direct way for my problem.

In advance, thanks

Comment: Have a look here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24127138/how-to-replace-a-rectangular-region-of-mat-image/24127841#comment37453115_24127841

Comment: there is no cvMat in opencv's java wrappers, so you must be using a 3rd party api. please clarify.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @medloh, the code should work, but it doesnt. Although I'm using opencv 2.4.8.